# GWT program run problem, please help GWT masters?

Tags: gwt

I try to run a example code from a book and it gives errors like:

```
[DEBUG] [rpc] - Validating newly compiled units
[ERROR] [rpc] - Errors in 'file:/D:/UserData/ge000001/workspace/RPC/src/rpc/client/HelloService.java'
[ERROR] [rpc] - Line 8: No source code is available for type rpc.server.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [rpc] - Errors in 'file:/D:/UserData/ge000001/workspace/RPC/src/rpc/client/HelloServiceAsync.java'
[ERROR] [rpc] - Line 9: No source code is available for type rpc.server.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [rpc] - Errors in 'file:/D:/UserData/ge000001/workspace/RPC/src/rpc/client/RPC.java'
[ERROR] [rpc] - Line 106: No source code is available for type rpc.server.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[TRACE] [rpc] - Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] [rpc] - Unable to find type 'rpc.client.RPC'
[ERROR] [rpc] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[ERROR] [rpc] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [rpc] - Failed to load module 'rpc' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1' at localhost:1802
```

these type errors occurs tomany times with tdifferent project and I cannot get the reason why?

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that for some reason GWT cannot find a class you're including in your code.

These errors usually occurs, and can be quite confusing, when something is fundamentally wrong with the configuration; usually something small and silly that breaks everything.

As the error message suggest it may be because its not included using `<inherits name="com.yourcompany.project.SomeClass"/>` or because java cannot find it (it's in a different path and not in the classpath or something like that).

It could also be that the classes include other classes/packages that cannot be converted to GWT code, and is ignored by GWT (stuff not in the core java packages). (Also if you use eclipse: it has an annoying habit of automatically add java `import` statements for stuff you mistype, see the problems tab and see if there are unused imports. You may have to change the preferences; setting "Unused imports" to "Warning", if it's not on by default.)

Try commenting out some of the includes and recompile, it may narrow down where the problem is. Use an IDE like Eclipse, and see if it reports errors. (I cannot give you any more specific help with the current data)